# How can I use tidyverse to loop through the dataset, perform multiple t tests conditionally on another variable and return all p values?

Tags: loops, while-loop, iteration, tidyverse

I would like to perform several t.tests to check the `math scores` differences between `base` conditionally on `quest`. After, check the `english scores` and the the `science scores`. By "hand", I'll have to loop within the dataset to do the following:

```
ds %>% filter(quest == "age_10") %>% {t.test(math ~ base, data = .)$p.value}
ds %>% filter(quest == "age_10") %>% {t.test(english ~ base, data = .)$p.value}
ds %>% filter(quest == "age_10") %>% {t.test(science ~ base, data = .)$p.value}

ds %>% filter(quest == "age_12") %>% {t.test(math ~ base, data = .)$p.value}
ds %>% filter(quest == "age_12") %>% {t.test(english ~ base, data = .)$p.value}
ds %>% filter(quest == "age_12") %>% {t.test(science ~ base, data = .)$p.value}
```

(etc)

Visually, my question is below
[image: question]

My hunt was almost there

```
ds %>%
    select(quest, base, math:science) %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = -c(quest, base))%>%
    group_by(quest) %>% 
    summarise(pout = list(broom::tidy(t.test(value ~ base, data = .)$p.value))) %>% 
    unnest(pout) %>% 
    as.data.frame()
```

CODE

```
ds <- data.frame(quest = rep(c("age_10","age_12","age_14","age_16"), each=10),
                 base = c("base1","base2"),
                 math = rnorm(80,10,2),
                 english = rnorm(80,8,1),
                 science = rnorm(80,13,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

if someone is looking for this answer, I could figure out the solution
Please use this following code

```
ds %>%
  select(quest, base, math:science) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(quest, base)) %>%
  group_by(quest, name)  %>%
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(p = map(data, ~t.test(.x$value ~ .x$base)$p.value)) %>% 
  unnest(p) %>% 
  select(-data)
```